# Extension causing issue with clear button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a placeHolder extension to give padding to the placeholder. But when I apply this class to my input field it doesn't show the clear button even if I select "Appears while editing" on the storyboard.

Can someone tell me how to fix it?

```
import UIKit

class textFiledplaceholder: UITextField {
static let font_size : CGFloat = 16
static let leftPadding : CGFloat = 15
static let righPadding : CGFloat = 15
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    self.comminIt()
}
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.comminIt()
}
func comminIt()
{
    borderStyle             = .none
    backgroundColor         = .white
    // layer.masksToBounds     = true
   
    setLeftPaddingPoints(textFiledplaceholder.leftPadding)
    setRightPaddingPoints(textFiledplaceholder.righPadding)
  }
 }

extension UITextField {
func setLeftPaddingPoints(_ amount:CGFloat){
    let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: amount, height: self.frame.size.height))
    self.leftView = paddingView
    self.leftViewMode = .always
}
func setRightPaddingPoints(_ amount:CGFloat) {
    let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: amount, height: self.frame.size.height))
    self.rightView = paddingView
    self.rightViewMode = .always
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set var clearButtonMode: UITextField.ViewMode { get set } to always for instance (by default it is never). I would try it in comminIt: self. clearButtonMode = .always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use rightview and clearbutton together. And if you are going to use a clear button then I don't think there is any use of right padding. Remove right padding and it will resolve your issue.

Comment: One more thing if you can help. Do you know how can we move clear button to the left? For example, if you check the image here: https://prnt.sc/tk30x7 the space on the left is more than the right.

Comment: You can reduce the left padding or you can use your custom right view.

Comment: Same as you were doing the right padding just place a button there.

Comment: So you're saying instead of using Apple's default clear button create a custom clear button?

Comment: Yes, if you need different button or different spacing... or else you can reduce left padding Same as clear button. It’s all yours.

Comment: Is it not possible that I give padding-right to the default clear button instead of creating a custom clear button? I appreciate your suggestion of reducing padding-left so it can be the same from left and right. but the whole point of the post is not to do it.

Comment: I think it’s not possible that you can give a right padding for clear button. I understand your point of using default clear button.